# Clearing input text field value with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I seem to be able to hide the resource container using

```
resource.parent().parent().hide();
```

but I don't understand why the input value is not clearing with

```
resource.parent().siblings('.resource-value').children('input').val('');
```

when I use

`resource.parent().siblings('.resource-value')` I get the parent of the input value but adding `.children('input').val('')` on top of that does nothing or if I add `.children('input:text').val('')`

I have very similar code for something else which works just fine, looked at other questions and not sure what I'm missing.

```js
function removeResource(resource) {
    'use strict';

    //hide resource on screen
    resource.parent().parent().hide();

    //set resource text value to ''
    resource.parent().siblings('.resource-value').children('input').val('');
}

(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $(function() {
        $('#resources').on('click', '.remove-resource', function(evt) {
            // Stop the anchor's default behavior
            evt.preventDefault();

            // Remove the image, toggle the anchors
            removeResource($(this));
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="resources">
     <div class="resource">
        <div class="resource-value">
           <input type="text" name="resources[]" value="1" />
        </div>
        <p class="hide-if-no-js"><a title="remove resource" href="javascript:;" class="remove-resource">remove resource</a > </p>
        <!-- .hide-if-no-js -->
     </div>
     <div class="resource">
        <div class="resource-value">
           <input type="text" name="resources[]" value="2"/>
        </div>
        <p class="hide-if-no-js"><a title="remove resourcee" href="javascript:;" class="remove-resource">remove resource</a> </p>
        <!-- .hide-if-no-js -->
     </div>
  </div>
   </body>
<html/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried your code and worked fine for me in terms of the actual value of the field clearing, though in inspector the HTML element still has the value attribute showing.

You can use

```
.attr('value','')
```

to clear that too http://jsfiddle.net/bvtg93dm

Comment: Interesting, thank you. This works in clearing any value from the inspector which solves the issue I was having.

Comment: I have a line in a nearly identical function similar html structure but this one is for removing images and the line  to remove an image goes image.siblings('.image-meta-info').children().val(''); This will also clear the value in the inspector so I'm wondering why things are different in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try to log your sibling element with 
Try to change your `removeResource` function to

```
function removeResource(resource) {

  'use strict';

  //hide resource on screen
  var parent = resource.parent().parent();
  parent.hide();

  // log your element
  console.log(parent.find('.resource-value input'));
  // make sure you are getting an element you need
  console.log(parent.siblings('.resource-value').childer('input').get(0);
  //set resource text value to ''
  parent.find('.resource-value input').val('');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to change the value witch jquery to set "" (so, empty).

```
input.attr('value','')
```